# Dual boot with partition containing virtual box

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, macosx, vagrant

Currently I use MacOS with a virtualbox that hosts my development vagrant environment. If I were to put that virtualbox and other directories I normally mount to the virtualbox onto a separate partition (using a file system that both MacOS and Ubuntu can use). Would I be able to safely dual boot into either OS interchangeably and safely use the virtualbox in both environments? Or does virtualbox have a separate format or something for each environment?

Comment: Looks like it might be possible (at least with Windows and a .vdi - I am using .vmdk) https://superuser.com/questions/68222/can-i-use-one-virtualbox-disk-for-multiple-machines

Comment: Yes, it's possible in most situations. Virtualbox is multi-platform. The same version should support the same file formats and settings irrespective of the OS it's running in.